# Put current playing song Title into document Title

Tags: javascript, html

I need to put change document title each time I change the song.

```js
function prevTrack() {
  if(this.trackPos == 0)
    this.setTrack(0);
  else
    this.setTrack(this.trackPos - 1);
    this.player.play(); 
    document.title = ???????????????
}

var classObj = this; // store scope for event listeners
this.shuffle = (config.shuffle === true) ? true : false;
this.playerId = (config.playerId) ? config.playerId : "audioPlayer";
this.playlistId = (config.playlistId) ? config.playlistId : "playlist";
this.currentClass = (config.currentClass) ? config.currentClass : "current-song"
this.length = $("#"+this.playlistId+" li").length; 
this.player = $("#"+this.playerId)[0];
this.autoplay = (config.autoplay === true || this.player.autoplay) ? true : false;
this.loop = (config.loop === true) ? true : false;
this.trackPos = 0;
this.trackOrder = [];
```

```html
<ul id="playlist">
  <li><a href="">song1</a></li> 
  <li><a href="">song2</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This what i m looking for                document.title = ???????????????

Comment: Yes, [`document.title`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/title) is exactly what you need to use. Is that the real question? It looks like you're using some undisclosed media player and you're asking for the API method to obtain track title. (BTW, your snippet throws a syntax error.)

Comment: Yes i need somthing like document.title= function( <li><a href="">song2</a></li>) a function that can extract "song2" from <li><a href="">song2</a></li>